# wordpress login user without open admin panel of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

is_user_logged_in()

I am trying to track if user is logged in or not, but above code only works if I will open my wordpress admin panel, is there any possible ways to check if user is logged in but not necessary he need to open his admin panel as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside `init` action.

```php
add_action('init', 'bks_run_code');

function bks_run_code()
{
   $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();
}
```

You need to make sure that wp functions are loaded and then you actually run the code you want. You can call other function inside `bks_run_code()`.

The code goes inside your `functions.php` file of your theme(child theme)